# Visual Studio code HTML Emmet is not formatted after I press tab

Tags: html, formatting, visual-studio-code, emmet

When I type `div>label+input+button:submit{Submit}` and press tab

Expected result:

```
<div>
    <label for=""></label>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Result I get:

```
<div><label for=""></label><input type="text"><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
```

How to fix this problem?

[image: Video]

Answer (score 1):

use Prettier - Code formatter.

Comment: Installing it alone doesn't change anything, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: sure, ctrl+shift+p => open settings (JSON) then =>

 "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },

Comment: Thank you for helping but sadly still not working... I installed prettier => set it as the default formatter then tried typed `div>label+input` and pressed tab and still the same result, then tried `ctrl+shift+p` format document with prettier and still the same (I will include the video in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Prettier will work but in your json file. you need to do

TLDR; You just need to replace `javascript` with the file type you are working in.

```
"[html]": {"editor.defaultFormatter":"esbenp.prettier-vscode"}
```

For example I use emmet with razor components. so my json file has this

```
"[razor]": {"editor.defaultFormatter":"esbenp.prettier-vscode"}
```